# IHTMLDocument Events are not working with the COM BrowserControl

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, events, mshtml

I'm trying to automate a website, and I have the following piece of code to change the value of a dropdown (select):

```
private bool ChangeElementSelection(mshtml.IHTMLDocument3 document, string id, string value)
    {

        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        if (el != null)
        {
            log.Write("Setting HTML element " + id + " value to " + value + " (by ID)");
            el.setAttribute("value", value);
            var el3 = (el as IHTMLElement3);
            el3.FireEvent("onchange");
            return true;
        }
        log.Write("Could not find HTML element " + id + " (by ID)");
        return false;
    }
```

The website I am visiting uses JQuery to catch the "change" event for the select element. It does not expect any parameters. Yet the script is not triggered. Why ?

Comment: you can also check whether el3 is not null.
check el3.FireEvent("onchange",null); you can also try el3.InvokeMember("onchange");

Comment: There is no method called InvokeMember, also el3 is not null. The SetAttribute part works fine.

Comment: have u tried  el3.FireEvent("onchange",null) ?
I was just checking http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/02c7a1fc-e9a8-4700-bfb1-33dc4daa388f/controlling-a-website-via-a-webbrowser-control

Comment: In http://www.itwriting.com/phorum/read.php?3,1507 someone also is adding a dummy event
Also check http://help.dottoro.com/ljvtddtm.php
I have used mshtml for couple of web crawling applications